# Deploying one application from two repo using Capistrano

Tags: capistrano

We have an application that is divided between two code repo: one public and one private. I would like to use Capistrano to deploy the application from these two locations and copy it to one directory.

For example:

public: github.com/app_public
private: github.com/app_private

application should be deployed to: hostname/home/myaccount/app